# How to create a context manager which is NOT a decorator?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a function which looks something like this:

```py
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def special_context(...):
    ...
    yield
    ...
```

It is appropriate for this to be used as a context manager, like this:

```py
with special_context(...):
    ...
```

... but it is *not* appropriate for it to be used as a decorator:

```py
# Not OK:
@special_context(...)
def foo():
    ...
```

I understand that Python 3.2 added decorator support to `contextlib.contextmanager`, but in my API it indicates a mistake which causes bugs. I like the ergonomics of `contextlib.contextmanager`, but I would like to prevent the API from being misused.

Is there a similar construct available (ideally in the standard libs) which would make `special_context` a context manager, but not a decorator?

Specifically, I want something like this:

```py
@contextmanager_without_decorator
def special_context(...):
    ...
    yield
    ...
```

Please help me to find or define `contextmanager_without_decorator`.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it: just document your reasons why `special_context` should not be used as a decorator, and let the user shoot themselves in the foot if they want.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you create your context manager as a class using `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, then by default it will not work as a decorator unless you also have it inherit from the `contextlib.ContextDecorator` base class.  That being said, I agree with chepner to not worry about it that much.  As Guido von Rossum said in regards to not having private vs public methods in Python: "we're all adults here".

Comment: "Don't worry about it" isn't acceptable for my use-case. This is driven by a real-world need to prevent bugs.

Comment: If another programmer is calling your API in a way that is not congruent with the correct usage of the API, that isn't a bug, that's a programmer error.

Comment: Semantics aside, the fact that my API can be called in this way causes problems. Preventing misuse in this way would prevent those problems. Let's focus on the technical aspect of this question, rather than how valid you believe my business needs are.

Comment: If you and your downstream users employ static typing, this is easily done by making a typing-only API which shadows the return type of `contextlib.contextmanager`. If you or your downstream users don't use static typing, you'll need to make an alternative runtime implementation of `@contextlib.contextmanager`; there isn't an stdlib solution AFAIK.

Comment: "you'll need to make an alternative runtime implementation of @contextlib.contextmanager; there isn't an stdlib solution AFAIK."

This is close to an acceptable answer. What would the implementation look like?

Comment: You would copy the existing `contextlib._GeneratorContextManager` impl but don't inherit from `ContextDecorator` (so that you don't inherit a `__call__` method, which is what enables decorator usage).

Comment: Note: when you use `contextlib.contextmanager`, the `yield` should be in a `try`, and the cleanup should be in a `finally`. Otherwise, cleanup will be skipped if an exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

[`contextlib.ContextDecorator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ContextDecorator) is the part of the return value of `@contextlib.contextmanager` which grants the ability to redecorate (in your case, `@special_context(...)`). The simplest way to prevent this from happening at runtime is to disable `contextlib.ContextDecorator.__call__`. The following is one possible implementation of `@contextmanager_without_decorator`, reproduced by tracing the runtime implementation of `@contextlib.contextmanager`:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing as t

import contextlib
import functools

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import collections.abc as cx
    import typing_extensions as tx

    _P = tx.ParamSpec("_P")
    _ContextManagerDecoratee: tx.TypeAlias = cx.Callable[_P, cx.Generator["_T_co", None, None]]

_T_co = t.TypeVar("_T_co", covariant=True)

class _GeneratorContextManager(contextlib._GeneratorContextManager[_T_co]):
    __call__: t.ClassVar[None] = None  # type: ignore[assignment]

def contextmanager_without_decorator(func: _ContextManagerDecoratee[_P, _T_co], /) -> cx.Callable[_P, _GeneratorContextManager[_T_co]]:
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def helper(*args: _P.args, **kwds: _P.kwargs) -> _GeneratorContextManager[_T_co]:
        return _GeneratorContextManager(func, args, kwds)

    return helper
```

```
@contextmanager_without_decorator
def special_context() -> cx.Generator[int, None, None]:
    yield 1

with special_context() as num:
    assert num == 1  # OK

# Re-decoration disabled
@special_context()
def foo():  # TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm impressed with the typing here, but I'm not keen on the idea of subclassing and then overriding an attribute to break some of its functionality. I think I'm more comfortable with more of a clean-slate approach.

Comment: @meshy sure - it’s more that `@contextlib.contextmanager` provides a whole heap of other functionality that I don’t know if your downstream users depend on. This was just one way of providing everything by default, except the ability to redecorate.

Comment: That's true -- my version is lacking a lot of what's provided out of the box. Still, I'd hope for a more additive, rather than subtractive approach.

Answer (score 1):

Probably to not use `contextlib` at all and just write your context manager as a class with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, rather than a function.

For example, your existing function context manager

```py
@contextmanager
def special_context(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
    yield 1
    ...
```

Can be rewritten with this usage like:

```py
class special_context:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __enter__(self):
        ...
        return 1

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        ...
```

```py
with special_context(...) as ctx:
    ... # works

@special_context(...)
def foo():
   ... # fails

@special_context
def foo():
    ...

foo() # fails
```

You could also modify the `__init__` to fail early if it indicates usage as a function decorator... assuming in practice that your context manager doesn't accept a function as a single positional parameter.

```py
class special_context:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) == 1 and not kwargs:
            if inspect.isfunction(args[0]):
                raise ValueError(f"You can't use {self.__class__.__name__} as a decorator")
        # ... rest as before
    # ...
```

Then usage as a decorator without arguments fails at definition time, rather than when the function is called:

```py
# fails at definition time with:
# ValueError: You can't use special_context as a decorator
@special_context
def foo(): 
    ...
```

You can also consider adding a `__call__` method that provides a more understandable error message like:

```py
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    raise ValueError(f"{self.__class__.__name__} cannot be used as a decorator")
```

To get the usage you desire, in a generalized form, you can write a small helper function, as you described in your [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78183049/5747944).

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the code in `contextlib`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/415964417771946dcb7a163951913adf84644b6d/Lib/contextlib.py#L202-L206), I've come up with this solution:

```py
def contextmanager_without_decorator(wrapped):
    class _ContextManager:

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.args = args
            self.kwargs = kwargs

        def __enter__(self):
            self.gen = wrapped(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            next(self.gen)

        def __exit__(self, *args):
            next(self.gen, None)

    return _ContextManager
```

The version in `contextlib` has more errorhandling around `next`, which perhaps this could benefit from, but this is a pleasing foundation.

Decoration now fails with an error to indicate the user's mistake:

```py
@special_context(...)
def foo():  # TypeError: '_ContextManager' object is not callable
    ...
```

Comment: This redefines the class on every usage.